# Disable Browser onUnload on certain links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, onunload

I am working on a Web Hosting panel which has a DNS records manager.  I have to use a lot of JavaScript to make it perform almost like a desktop application.

I really wanted to show a Custom Dialog window when a a browser runs `beforeunload` however after some research I have discovered I am stuck using the browsers default Dialog window.

So this JavaScript code below does just that, my problem is I need to make sure it does NOT get fired off on certain link clicks.

I am hoping to be able to maintain an Array of CSS class names, and if the link clicked is in this array then it will NOT show the onunload event.

I'm sure this is easy for a JavaScript developer.  Could someone show me how to do this?

```
//sample Class array
safeLinks = ['test', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4', 'test5'];

// onunload event
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could remove the event handler when they're clicked:

```
var safeLinks = ['.test', '.test2', '.test3', '.test4', '.test5'];

function promptBeforeClose() {
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
}

$(window).on('beforeunload', promptBeforeClose);

$(document).on('click', safeLinks.join(', '), function(e) {
    $(window).off('beforeunload', promptBeforeClose);
});
```

Also, if these safe links have a common ancestor, use that instead of `document` as the delegation parent or people will complain. ;)

Comment: I have a problem with your script. I have a page where people can edit some photos. There people can also delete photos, and when they press on delete a confirmation appeares. I added that button on `safeLinks`. Your script works perfect untill someone clicks on delete. If they cancel the confirmation your script stops working. How can I fix this? I need to turn `on` the `beforeunload` that is set `off` each time someone clicks on delete and cancel deleting confirmation.

Comment: @sorinu26: You can cancel bubbling on that event. `e.stopPropagation();` inside your confirmation listener.

Answer (score 1):

use a flag variable.When ever click on the onload then make it as true

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
 if(flag != false)
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```