# Making the leaving site confirm dialog not showing up when a button on the page is clicked

Tags: javascript

I recently added a JavaScript dialog into my page, which will let the user confirm if they really want to leave the page. However, I also have buttons navigating to other pages on my page, and I don't want the leaving site confirm dialog to show up when users click these buttons.

I haven't really found out a way on how to do this, partly because I'm new to HTML and JavaScript.

Below is my code I'm using for the confirm dialog, which I also got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser) on Stack Overflow.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    if (e) {     // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
        e.returnValue = 'Any string';
    }

    return 'Any string';     // For Safari
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Browser onUnload on certain links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116230/disable-browser-onunload-on-certain-links), [javascript onbeforeunload disable for links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932464/javascript-onbeforeunload-disable-for-links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a global variable to control the way to navigate.

Here is an example, I use a variable called `needConfirm` to handle the webpage will show confirm message or not.

```
var needConfirm = true;
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  if (!needConfirm) {
    return; // do nothing, just redirect...
  }

  e = e || window.event;

  if (e) {     // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    e.returnValue = 'Any string';
  }

  return 'Any string';     // For Safari
};

// function to change needConfirm value to `false`
function disableConfirm() {
  needConfirm = false;
}
```

Call disableConfirm() onClick for button and links which you want to allow. E.g.

```
<a href="/other_page_url" onClick="disableConfirm()">Redirect without confirmation...</a>
```